# Cleaning up pdftotext font issues

Tags: pdf, conversion, special-characters, ascii

I'm using `pdftotext` to make an ASCII version of a PDF document (made with LaTeX), because collaborators prefer a simple document in MS Word.

The plain text version I see looks good, but upon closer inspection the f character seems to be frequently mis-converted depending on what characters follow. For example, fi and fl often seem to become one special character, which I will try to paste here: ﬁ and ﬂ.

What is the best way to clean up the output of pdftotext? I am thinking `sed` might be the right tool, but I'm not sure how to detect these special characters.

Comment: fl, fi, ff, ffl, and ffi are common typographic ligatures, commonly replaced by a single character (and definitely with TeX): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Computer_typesetting - perhaps you just need to check that the font you're viewing the output in has them, and that the encoding is right.

Comment: oh, and you mean `pdftotext` from poppler, right, not `pdftotex` ?

Comment: Do you have the original TeX source? Why not use, e.g., latex2rtf or oolatex (from TeX4ht) to generate a Word Processor file for the Word junkies? Compiling to PDF and then converting to plain text seems like a very weird route for conversion.

Comment: Oh, and if you DO want to convert PDF to plain text, consider using `ebook-convert` from calibre (http://calibre-ebook.com) rather than `pdftotext`. It allows plain text output (and a variety of other formats), and handles ligatures for you.

Comment: I did mean pdftotex*t*. Typo fixed. I have original TeX source, but latex2rtf and oolatex do not work as well as pdftotext. I use additional packages like `siunitx` and `glossaries`, and therefore it seems like going via the PDF is the best solution. I wish there were a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the `ebook-convert` suggestion, that seems to work better than `pdftotext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `pdftotext` outputs unicode (UTF-8) data. If your terminal or text editor doesn't support UTF-8, ligatures such as "fi" and "fl" (which can be represented as a single character in unicode) will appear strangely, as you have noticed.

The simple fix is to tell `pdftotext` to output ASCII instead of unicode:

```
pdftotext -enc ASCII7 input.pdf output.txt
```

This should produce clean ASCII output, removing your need to clean it up manually afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I found the `ebook-convert` suggestion above to be the best. Your advice might improve the default behavior of `pdfottext`, but I think my terminal does support UTF-8, and `ebook-convert` seems to handle superscripts and other things better.

Comment: this solution will also not work if you actually need unicode characters in your output.

Comment: The problem with this is, you can end up with words like `dene` for `define` or `suer` for `suffer`. Converting to ASCII directly will automatically strip all ligatures and won't bother trying to convert them to their ASCII alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're on some kind of Unix-based system, you could run this on the output of pdftotext:

```
sed -i -e 's/ﬃ/ffi/g' -e 's/ﬁ/fi/g' -e 's/ﬀ/ff/g' -e 's/ﬂ/fl/g' -e 's/ﬄ/ffl/g' output.txt
```

That should replace the ligatures with the individual letters they break into. (See my comments above for what ligatures have to do with this.)

I tested that on a text file generated through `pdftotext` from a LaTeX-generated PDF. And it worked fine. But if the LaTeX used a nonstandard encoding or font with additional ligatures there may be more to do.

You'll probably want to make sure the font you're using in your terminal has characters for the f-series ligatures. DejaVu Sans Mono is a good choice.

Comment: In case your terminal is not utf-8 (for example windows cmd.exe), you can also do this with the byte representation: `sed -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x80/ff/g' -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x81/fi/g' -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x82/fl/g' -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x83/ffi/g' -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x84/ffl/g' -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x85/ft/g' -e 's/\\xEF\\xAC\\x86/st/g'`.

Comment: I did a similar process by converting to UTF-8 with `pdftotext -enc UTF-8`, and then I simply copied the UTF-8 characters and replaced them with their correct ASCII counterparts. I eyeballed the original PDF to make sure it made sense for characters which had no direct ASCII counterpart.